# iptables blocking access to forwarded port

Tags: iptables, docker

I have server with several docker containers installed.

Port 3306 is forwarder to some docker container.

I want to block this port, but in a way I do not break docker.

I did this,
since only ports 22 and 80 are only ports in list, all other ports supposed to be closed.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport    22      -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport    80      -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT                           -j DROP
```

...howver this obviously not work, because Docker installed its rules in FORWARD channel.

Any ideas how I can fix this easily, without "touching" docker containers?

Comment: The `INPUT_F` chain is not a standard chain. Either you or a firewall script added it. Can you add to the question the output of `iptables -nL INPUT` and `iptables -nL FORWARD`.

Comment: yes, redacting. sorry. INPUT_F was same as INPUT

Comment: You should delete the `DNAT` rule as explained in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/803772/remove-exposed-port-from-docker) and [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27549509/remove-port-binding-from-an-existing-docker-container).

Comment: I can not do so, because I am not familiar with the application

Comment: Then add `iptables -t nat -nL DOCKER` to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I come up with.

The answer I am supping, does not do ***exactly*** what the question asks. Instead of blocking access, it allow access only from specific IP addresses, but blocking access is trivial now.

https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/

The article explains that you can use `DOCKER-USER` chain to do things like this. Docker do not clear or manipulate this chain in any way.

My setup is as follows:
(note `INPUT_F` and `DOCKER-USER_F` are not standard chains, I defined them)

```
#!/bin/sh

# Turbo mode
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle

# Disable ip_forward
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
#Enable SYN Cookies
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies

#========================================================

DEV_EXTERNAL=enp2s0

#========================================================

iptables -N INPUT_F
iptables -N HOSTS_ALLOW
iptables -N DOCKER-USER
iptables -N DOCKER-USER_F

#========================================================

iptables -F INPUT
iptables -F INPUT_F
iptables -F HOSTS_ALLOW
iptables -F DOCKER-USER
iptables -F DOCKER-USER_F

#========================================================

iptables -P INPUT   ACCEPT

#========================================================

iptables -A INPUT       -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A DOCKER-USER -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT       -i $DEV_EXTERNAL    -j INPUT_F
iptables -A DOCKER-USER -i $DEV_EXTERNAL    -j DOCKER-USER_F

#========================================================

iptables -A INPUT_F -p tcp --dport  22      -j HOSTS_ALLOW
iptables -A INPUT_F -p tcp --dport  2022    -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT_F                         -j DROP

#========================================================


iptables -A DOCKER-USER_F -p tcp --dport    80  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A DOCKER-USER_F -p tcp --dport    443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A DOCKER-USER_F                       -j HOSTS_ALLOW

#========================================================

iptables -A HOSTS_ALLOW     -s 199.217.118.213  -j ACCEPT
iptables -A HOSTS_ALLOW     -s 185.154.12.78    -j ACCEPT
iptables -A HOSTS_ALLOW     -s 46.200.74.21     -j ACCEPT
iptables -A HOSTS_ALLOW                         -j DROP

#========================================================

# iptables -L -n -v

# iptables-save > /etc/iptables/iptables.rules
```

## Update

I did made some changes, because I seems to broke internet access in docker containers.

Comment: So you did not want to block access to port `3306`, but just restrict it to two external hosts?

Comment: well. the solution does not do exactly what I asked. i do not drop only 3306. i am rewtricting all but 80 and 443. but drop will be elementary now

Comment: iptables -A DOCKER-USER_F -p tcp --dport    3306 -j DROP

Comment: `iptables -t nat -D DOCKER -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to-destination <internal_machine_IP>` will disable forwarding, so you won't need a `DROP` rule.

Comment: i dont know if the application uses forwarding on internal network. also i need to do this on several ports. thanks for the tip, will have it in mind.